# The way to instantiate map<String, List<String>> in Java

Tags: java, list, dictionary, generic-programming

I would like to instantiate `Map<String, List<String>>` in Java,

I tried

```
Map<String, List<String>> foo = new <String, List<String>>();
```

and

```
Map<String, List<String>> foo = new <String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

None of them work. Does any one know how to instantiate this map in Java?

Answer (score 29):

```
new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

or as gparyani commented:

```
new HashMap<>(); // type inference
```

Note: each entry needs to be given an instantiated List as a value. You cannot get("myKey").add("some_string_for_this_key"); the very first time you get() a List from it.

So, fetch a List, check if it's null.

If it's null, make a new list, add the string to it, put the List back.
If it's anything but null, add to it, or do what you want.

Comment: ...or you can just say `new HashMap<>();` as of Java 7

Answer (score 16):

You forgot to mention the class. `Map` here is the reference type and is an *Interface*. `HashMap` on the other side of equals specifies the *actual* type of the *Object* created and assigned to the reference `foo`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> foo = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

The actual type specified (`HashMap` here) must be **assignable** to the reference type (`Map` here) i.e. if the type of reference is an *Interface*, the Object's type must *implement* it. And, if the type of the reference is a *Class*, the Object's type must either be the same *class* or its *subtype* i.e. it extends from it.

From Java 7 onwards, you can use a shorthand like

```
Map<String, List<String>> foo = new HashMap<>();
```

Your second way of instantiation is **not** recommended. Stick to using `List` which is an *Interface*.

```
// Don't bind your Map to ArrayList
new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

// Use List interface type instead
new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Answer (score 6):

Map is an interface.  You have to tell Java which concrete Map class you want to instantiate.

```
Map<String, List<String>> foo = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

or

```
Map<String, List<String>> foo = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
```

etc.